# Shopify - Checkbox being unchecked during checkout

Tags: reactjs, shopify

I have a problem with Shopify Checkout Extensibility.

The goal is simple - add a checkbox into the checkout pages.

I'm using a REACT app to do so and I'm able  to relatively easily add a checkbox using Checkout UI extensions.

The problem is that the checkout is being unchecked every time the shipping costs are being recalculated.

There are many tutorial on how to solve this problem, but honestly not one of them is fixing it on my side.

See below for the code, if you have any ideas I would be very grateful.

```
import {
  reactExtension,
  Checkbox,
  useApplyMetafieldsChange,
  useMetafield
} from '@shopify/ui-extensions-react/checkout';

export default reactExtension(
  'purchase.checkout.reductions.render-after',
  () => <Extension />,
);

function Extension() { 
  const checkedValue = useMetafield({
    namespace: "checkoutcustomizer",
    key: "adddirectsignature_v1"
  })

  const setChange = useApplyMetafieldsChange();

  return (
    <Checkbox 
      checked={checkedValue?.value}
      onChange={ (value) => {
        setChange({
          type: "updateMetafield",
          namespace: "checkoutcustomizer",
          key: "adddirectsignature_v1",
          valueType: "string",
          value
        })
      }}>
      Add Direct Signature
    </Checkbox>
  );
}
```

Comment: "*the checkout is being unchecked every time the shipping costs are being recalculated*" - Are you using ajax to calculate shipping and if so are you sure you are not just rerendering your UI after the shipping is calculated

Comment: @DarkBee The shipping is being calculated by Shopify, I'm using standard template on a dev store so there's not even a line of a custom code. I assume they're using AJAX to calculate the shipping, as the site is not being reloaded, but the only thing that is being rendered is the shipping cost, not the entire cart. So in my opinion it shouldn't affect the checkbox that is not a part of the shipping cost DIV.

Comment: Did you verify this with the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: I did. There's only one AJAX request when the shipping cost is being calculated again, but it doesn't do anything to this part of DOM. Even when I block all the AJAX request the problem still occurs.